# How to show an SQL calculated column in CGridView

Tags: mysql, sql, yii

These are the database table i have:

## trip

- id
- capacity
- ...

## tripRegisteration

- id
- tripId
- firstname
- lastname
- phone
- ...
- registerationState

## sql query

I want a sql query which will give me the trips which has enough free capacity. The tripRegisteration.registerationState for valid registeration is `approved`. this is the sql query:

```
SELECT t.*,count(*) as registeredNum 
FROM trip t 
left join 
    (select * 
            from trip_registeration tr
            where tr.registerationState="approved"
            ) trlist
    on t.id =trlist.tripId 
group by t.id
having t.capacity>registeredNum
```

## Yii Code

This is the Yii PHP code for getting the data provider in `DBTrip` activerecord model

```
public function getAvailableTripsDataProvider()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select = 't.*, COUNT( * ) AS registeredNum';
    $criteria->join =
    'left join (select *
    from trip_registeration tr
    where tr.applicationState="initialized"
    ) trlist
    on t.id =trlist.tripId';
    $criteria->group = 't.id';
    $criteria->having = 't.capacity > registeredNum';

    return new CActiveDataProvider ( 'DBTrip', array (
            'criteria' => $criteria
    )
}
```

## problem

Everything is just working fine except that i cant get the value of `registerednNum` in the CGridView, the `'value' => 'var_dump($data)'` just show the properties of the corresponding DBTrip Row, and it doesn't have any info about `registeredNum`. How i can show it in a CGridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `registeredNum` as public property to your `DBTrip` model:

```
class DBTrip extends CActiveRecord{
    public $registeredNum;
```

Apart from that, i wonder why you do that unneccessary subselect. You could just add that condition to your `ON` clause which makes your query much more readable.

```
$criteria->join ='left join trip_registration tr ON 
    t.id=trlist.tripId AND tr.applicationState="initialized"';
```

Comment: about sub select, because the left join wouldn't give me the results where there is no `tr` because the `on` criteria is not `true` ... thank you it worked :)

Comment: The left join *does* give you back the same result. Did you try it?

Comment: yes i did believe me it doesn't:) . i hadn't the courage to make a subselect (just like you) but i had to. it seems that if one of the columns in the `on` state doesn't relate to `t` like `tr.applicationState="initialized"` the statement would be expressed as `false`.